# NAS mount on CentOS, remount on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, mount, nfs

I have a NAS that is mounted on a CentOS box. I have Ubuntu 12.04 on another box. Is it possible to mount the NAS on the Ubuntu box via the CentOS box? Heres a diagram:

`NAS:/Public -> CentOS:/Library -> Ubuntu:/Library`

I keep getting the error when I try to mount the NAS on Ubuntu going through the CentOS box:

```
RPCPROG_NFS: RPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Timed out
```

The NAS is running `busybox` and I don't see an `/etc/rc.conf` which seemed to be the obvious place to look. There's also only a `hosts` file and not a `hosts.allow` file.

Comment: Is the error you posted with an attempt to connect from Ubuntu directly to your NAS or some attempt to do this via the CentOS host? Please clarify the **exact** steps you're performing by **editing** your question.

Comment: Updated the question, its when I try to mount the NAS on Ubuntu when I go through CentOS.